# multiple background images with linear gradient overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

My [codepen](http://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/full/jygeJM/) shows this introduction page background image with a 2nd multiple background image containing a linear gradient. The problem is when the browser is resized the image is reduced and the linear gradient remains the same height.  How can I dynamically change the gradient height to match the 1st background image height? [image]

Note: I do not want to use `background-size: cover` as it cuts off too much of the image.

The body gap (color: #454545) between the navbar and background image seems particular to codepen.  It doesn't appear when I run the webpage locally.

Answer (score 1):

Base on my experience, CSS is not that flexible when the surrounding environment changes. Two solutions pop up in my mind.

1. Using JS to add inline CSS dynamically based on the current box size
2. Create multiple media query based on your needs

Comment: I will investigate using javascript.  Eventually will add media queries too as I want both the display to be both responsive and adaptive.

Comment: Here's a new [codepen](http://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/full/yMyXBN/) to show the JS I used to resize the element based on the size of the image.  Hope this helps someone.